# Rejection/Importance Sampling for logit model

Tags: simulation, logit, importance-sampling, rejection-sampling

$\newcommand{\logit}{\operatorname{logit}}$I have the following model:

${y}_{j}\sim \operatorname{Bin}({n}_{j},{\theta}_{j})$, where ${\theta}_{j}={\logit}^{-1}(\alpha+\beta{x}_{j})$, for $j=1,...,J$, and with independent priors $\alpha\sim {t}_{4}(0,2^{2})$ , $\beta\sim {t}_{4}(0,1)$. And finally we use J=10, and ${x}_{j}\sim U(0,1)$,  ${n}_{j}\sim {\operatorname{Poisson}}^{+}(5)$

**Question:** how can I use Importance Sampling/Rejection Sampling for draw posterior simulations? I mean, I want to use the fact about the independence to first draw simulations for $\alpha$ and then simulations for $\beta$. My $q\left( \theta |y \right)$ would be:

$q\left( \theta |y \right) =p\left( \alpha ,\beta |n,x \right) p\left( y|\alpha ,\beta ,n,x \right) =p\left( \alpha ,\beta  \right) \displaystyle\prod _{ i=1 }^{ K }{ p\left( { y }_{ i }|\alpha ,\beta ,{ n }_{ i },{ x }_{ i } \right)  } =p\left( \alpha ,\beta  \right){({\logit}^{-1}(\alpha+\beta{x}_{j}))}^{y_{i}}{(1-{\logit}^{-1}(\alpha+\beta{x}_{j}))}^{n_{i}-y_{i}} $

And maybe I'm wrong, but I understand that If I wanna use independence, I would have to "get rid" of anything containing $\beta$ (for $p(\alpha|y)$) (marginalizing?)

Any suggestions or corrections? I was also thinking about $g(\alpha)={t}_{4}(0,2^{2})$ and $g(\beta)={t}_{4}(0,1)$

Comment: You are wrong about the independence: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not independent in the posterior distribution.

Answer (score 5):

A natural importance sampling distribution in this setting is a Gaussian distribution$$\text{N}(\hat{\theta},\tau^2\hat{\Sigma})$$
where

1. $\hat\theta$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $(\alpha,\beta)$;
2. $\hat{\Sigma}$ is the asymptotic covariance matrix of $\hat\theta$;
3. $\tau^2$ is a scaling factor that can be calibrated towards optimising the resulting effective sample size.

Note that, as remarked in our book [Bayesian Essentials with R](http://amzn.to/2kxP1vO) (p.115-117), one can also exploits this approximation in a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. Deriving the asymptotic matrix can be done in R as

```
> mod=summary(glm(y~X,family=binomial(link="probit")))
```

with `mod$coeff[,1]` corresponding to $\hat\theta$ and `mod$cov.unscaled`
to $\hat\Sigma$.

Comment: +1. Quite an intuitive answer, Xi'an. Would there happen to be a reference for this choice of importance distribution; a place where this has been implemented in the literature?

Comment: @Greenparker: thanks. While this is not exactly the same thing, using the Laplace approximation to the posterior appears frequently as a suggestion in the MCMC literature.

Comment: right, of course. I was actually interested in the use of ESS to tune $\tau^2$, the tuning factor. But yes, the Laplace approximation is indeed on the same lines of the approximation.